# Aligning divs horizontally inside a div that hides overflow

Tags: html, css

Say I have this HTML:

```
<style>
.b{
float:left; width: 300px; height: 300px;
}
</style>

<div style="overflow:hidden;width:300px;height:300px;" id="a">
    <div class="b" style="background-color: red"></div>
    <div class="b" style="background-color: green"></div>
    <div class="b" style="background-color: blue"></div>
</div>
```

I want the `.b` divs to sit on one line. However, they only do this when `#a`'s overflow is normal.

Comment: your #a have the size of 300px x 300px - so in this situation you can only see the red div every .b-element have the width of 300px so you have to change the width of #a to 900p - what exactly do you like to have?

Comment: u have parent element of 300px, u have 3 children, each of 300px..how can u fit them inside??..isn't it logically wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to `#a` and remove float:left from `.b`

**With scrollbar**

```
#a{overflow:auto;width:300px;height:300px; white-space: nowrap;}
.b{
width: 300px; height: 300px; border:solid black 1px; display:inline-block
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xhgmU/3/)**

---

**Without scrollbar**

```
#a{height:300px; white-space: nowrap;}
.b{
width: 300px; height: 300px; border:solid black 1px; display:inline-block
}​
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/xhgmU/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add the css property **display:inline-block**.

Rewrite

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;width:300px;height:300px;" id="a">
```

to

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;width:300px;height:300px;display:inline-block" id="a">
```

Answer (score 0):

your #a have the size of 300px x 300px - so in this situation you can only see the red div the 3 elements can^t fit in an element with a smaller size
every .b-element have the width of 300px so you have to change the width of #a to 900px -

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is give a `display:inline-block;` style to your class b. and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

`Overflow` is just a property that is saying that it can not go larger then 300px;

So in order to stack them next to each other use the property `float:left;` and make sure you stay inside the 300px;

**Example**

```
<style>
.b{
float:left; width: 100px; height: 300px;
}
</style>

<div style="overflow:hidden;width:300px;height:300px;" id="a">
    <div class="b" style="background-color: red"></div>
    <div class="b" style="background-color: green"></div>
    <div class="b" style="background-color: blue"></div>
</div>
```